# Alert log information in 10g

Tags: oracle10g, alert

I need some clarification on 
Create, alter and drop SQL statements on databases,tablespaces and rollback segments.
related to ALERT LOG.

Does Alert log contain information about 'CREATE' or 'DROP' on tables?
Does Alert log contain information about  'WHO CREATED' or 'WHO DROPPED'  tables?

P.S. The database version is 10.2.0.4 on windows 2003 operating system.

Comment: After AUDIT is set up: will the Alert Log show the information as to who created or dropped tables and also what tables got created or dropped?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways: the first with audit

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> SHOW PARAMETER AUDIT

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
audit_file_dest                      string      C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ADMIN\XE\ADUMP
audit_sys_operations                 boolean     FALSE
audit_trail                          string      NONE
SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET audit_trail=db SCOPE=SPFILE;

System altered.

SQL> startup force
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1068937216 bytes
Fixed Size                  2260048 bytes
Variable Size             616563632 bytes
Database Buffers          444596224 bytes
Redo Buffers                5517312 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.

SQL> AUDIT ALL BY hr BY ACCESS;

Audit succeeded.

SQL> conn hr/hr
Connected.
SQL> create table ttt(id number);

Table created.

SQL> drop table ttt;

Table dropped.

SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  SELECT username
  2       , extended_timestamp
  3       , owner
  4       , obj_name
  5       , action_name
  6    FROM dba_audit_trail
  7*  order by 2
SQL> /

USERNAME   EXTENDED_TIMESTAMP                  OWNER      OBJ_NAME   ACTION_NAME
---------- ----------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------------------------
HR         14.08.14 18:00:35,606000 +04:00                           LOGON
HR         14.08.14 18:00:48,651000 +04:00     HR         TTT        CREATE TABLE
HR         14.08.14 18:00:54,425000 +04:00     HR         TTT        DROP TABLE
HR         14.08.14 18:00:59,311000 +04:00                           LOGOFF
```

Second with the DBMS_LOGMNR package.